# Protecting applications IBM worklight

Tags: mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to IBM worklight; I have been trying to implement app-level form authentication for an hybrid android app without success.
What I did: 
add 
`<android securityTest="try" version="1.0">` 
to my application-descriptor.xml, where try is defined as follows:

```
<mobileSecurityTest name="try">
            <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
            <testUser realm="myMobileLoginForm" />
 </mobileSecurityTest>

<realm loginModule="requireLogin" name="myMobileLoginForm">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-page" value="login.html" />
</realm>
```

From what I understood from the docs, this should redirect users to the sample login.html on startup where I can manage the client-side user actions with a ChallengeHandler.
However the securityTest="try" attribute does nothing at all. 
Please tell me what if i missed something huge, which seems to be the case...

EDIT: I get the login.html as server response now, guess I should display it with javascript

FINAL EDIT : In case someone encounters similar issues, here is what i did in the challenge handler:

`login_clientside.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
        document.body.innerHTML = response.responseText;
    //alert('test');
    return false;
};`

Of course this is without the UI part to get a nice looking login page-- and the security part.

Comment: Did you try following the form-based authentication training module and sample project?

Comment: You probably did not implement the challenge handler in your client code, or forgot to import/include it, and/or forgot to add the login.html and loginError.html pages. See @Jaalger2 's answer below for more details.

Comment: @DanielGonzalez Thanks for your answer; I copied the login.html page from server/conf to myApp/common; I do not have a loginError.html. Where should I put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worklight provides a tutorial presentation along with an accompanying sample that you can run in test that does Form-Based Authentication.

**Form-Based Authentication Presentation**

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/08_02_Form_based_authentication.pdf

**Form-Based Authentication Sample**

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/FormBasedAuthenticationProject.zip

Since you stated you are new to Worklight I would suggest reading through this presentation and then attempt running the sample inside of Worklight Studio. Once you understand the concepts and have the sample running correctly you should have no problem incorporating these techniques into your project. Let me know if you have any specific questions.

Comment: I followed the sample and did a form which hides the login form and shows my main page content upon login; however, I want to protect the whole application because I guess one could just modify the css properties to see the main page without logging in? Is it possible to do the login process before accessing the application?

Comment: You could protect the application using a securityTest inside of the applicationDescriptor. If the app connects on startup and the application is protected by a security test the user will have to login on startup. Please go through the authentication modules under the authentication section here:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html

As well as security information in the infocenter:

https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.doc%2Fwl_home.html

Comment: I did go through the documentation several times - i deleted <parameter name="login-page" value="login.html" /> and now i get login.html as the server response in the worklight logs. I think the corporate proxy is causing issues, since I get random prompts to login on app startup. j_security_check is not found half of the time also for no particular reason. I will mark your answer as accepted for your time and sort this out myself.